# Writing TR and TD tags as Inner HTML of a DIV / TD

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I am writing a table inside a DIV using the JavaScript innerHTML property

```
listing.innerHTML += '<table> <tr><td><img src='+ pic + friends[a].split("|")[1] + '/picture"' + ' class="pic" /></td>'; 

listing.innerhtml += '<td class="name">' + friends[a].split("|")[0] + "</td>";

listing.innerHTML += "<td><button id='add' onclick=write() /> </td> </tr> </table>";
```

To the div with the ID 'listing' , the content is written without the table tags i.e. `<td> </td> </tr> <tr>`.

i.e. the required content appears but is not formatted as an HTML Table. When I look at the source in a browser, the TR and TD and closure tags for the same are missing.. Any idea why? I am using Chrome.

Comment: Build the string then set the innerHTML. When you set innerHTML, the browser will attempt to fix the content if the HTML is malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tbl = '<table> <tr><td><img src='+ pic + friends[a].split("|")[1] + '/picture"' + ' class="pic" /></td>';
tbl += '<td class="name">' + friends[a].split("|")[0] + "</td>";
tbl += "<td><button id='add' onclick=write() /> </td> </tr> </table>";

listing.innerHTML += tbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the DOM is updated each time you add content to the innerHTML, and the browser closes the unclosed `<table>` for you.

I'd recommend you generating the whole html and then adding it to innerHTML at once:

```
var myhtml = "";
myhtml += '<table> <tr><td><img src="'+ pic + friends[a].split("|")[1] + '/picture"' + ' class="pic" /></td>'; 
myhtml += '<td class="name">' + friends[a].split("|")[0] + "</td>";
myhtml += "<td><button id='add' onclick='write()' /> </td> </tr> </table>";
listing.innerHTML += myhtml;
```

**Note:** also make sure you are enclosing all the attribute values in matching quotes (either douple or single, but they must match). Attribute values without quotes are unsupported, altough they might work sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the changes you are making do not appear when you view the source of the page, that's fine. It's because it's not getting updated from changes you are making via JS in the DOM.

Have a look at using Firefox/Firebug

> Inspect HTML and modify style and layout in real-time.